# Getting an InvalidDataException extracting .zip file in Windows Store App with ZipArchive

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, zip

I am working on a Windows Store app proof of concept that will open a .zip file and extract the contents to an app-specific Roaming folder. I have looked into several popular libraries to extract the contents only to find that these libraries don't support Windows Store apps (at least not yet). So, I have decided to go with [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx). I have the following code in a button click handler:

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".zip");
    var openedFile = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    var booksFolder = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Stuff", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    var folder = await booksFolder.CreateFolderAsync(openedFile.Name.Replace(".zip", string.Empty), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var stream = await openedFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
            {
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(entry.Name);
                    using (var decompressedStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                    {
                        using (var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(entryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        {
                            await deflateStream.CopyToAsync(decompressedStream, (int)entry.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get an `InvalidDataException` on the line

```
await deflateStream.CopyToAsync(decompressedStream, (int)entry.Length);
```

Here's the details of the exception:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.IO.Stream.<BeginEndReadAsync>b__e(Stream stream, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsyncInternal>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at POC.MoviePlayer.GroupedItemsPage.<Button_Click_1>d__4.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Brent\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\POC.MoviePlayer\POC.MoviePlayer\GroupedItemsPage.xaml.cs:line 108
  InnerException:
```

The .zip file I am trying to import was created with Windows Explorer's Send To Compressed (Zipped) Folder option. I have also tried to create a .zip file in code, using ZipArchive, but I get more exceptions with that code too. Since that isn't my ideal use case anyway, I won't include my code to create the .zip unless it turns out to be useful to somebody.

I am hoping somebody can either see the error of my ways in the code above or provide a link to a solid library to work with zip files that is preferably open source. This frustrated developer would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to decompress the result of `entry.Open()`. It is already decompressed.

You could also use `ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttodirectory.aspx) to simplify your code.

Comment: I swear that I tried without decompressing and was getting other exceptions, but I must have messed something else up while I was doing it. I took the DeflateStream out of my method above and it worked like a charm. The ExtractToDirectory sounds awesome too, but will it work with ApplicationData.RoamingFolder and ApplicationData.LocalFolder?

Comment: These folders should be located somewhere in the filesystem (not 100% shure, because I have no experience with Win8), therefore you could just use `folder.Path`.

Comment: It looks like they may have left the ExtractToDirectory extension method out of the WinRT api on purpose (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/7906fd37-3918-46c0-b698-920fa2cf0835). That thread is over a year old, but I'm not seeing it in the Object Browser either. Bummer. Either way, you solved my problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: I am not sure that its already decoded when using Open? I could not upload the stream to Azure Storage with the UploadFromStream, but using CopyTo a memory stream before upload worked. Like CopyTo decoded teh stream.